# Table structure of a student

Tags: sql

I want a table structure which can store the details of the student like the below format.

If the student is in
                   10 th standard -> I need his aggregate % from 1st standard to 9th standard.
                   5 th standard -> I need his aggregate % from 1st standard to 4th standard.
                   1 st standard -> No aggregate % has to be displayed.

And the most important thing is ' we need to use only one table'. Please form a table structure with no redundant values.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated......

No friends this is not a home work. This is asked in Oracle interview, conducted in Hyderabad day before yesterday '24th July, 2010',. He asked me the table structure.

He even did not asked me the query. He asked me how I will design the table. Please advice me.

Comment: I think you're looking for a query, and not a table? (You could output the query result into the table, if you want). Edit: also, to help other answerers: what to do if the student is not in 10th, 5th or 1st standard?

Comment: Screams homework to me, you want to put any effort into solving the problem at all?

Comment: Is this homework?  There is a homework tag.

Comment: yes, agreed (re screeming homework). should have dressed the question up a little more... :)

Comment: The homework tag *might* not apply here.

Comment: If it's asked in an interview, and you can't answer it, I don't think you have passed the interview. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
id | name | grade | aggregate
```

This would do the trick, id is your primary key, name is students first last name, grade is what grade he is in and aggregate is aggregate % based on the grade.

```
Fro example some rows might be:
10 | Bill Cosby | 10 | 90
11 | Jerry Seinfeld | 4 | 60
```

Bill Cosby would have aggregate percent of 90 in grades 1-9, and jerry would have 60 in grades 1-3.  In this case it is one table and boils down to you managing the rule of aggregation for this table, since it has to be one table.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. 

But the thing is we don't need the aggregate of all the years, but for every year. Like -> The roll no of student, his 1st standard aggregate, 2nd standard aggregate, 3rd standard aggregate .......... so on. So when a student is selected we will be able to see his total academic progress. 

I told them two answers
1. creating 10 columns for every standard. This was put as wrong because of unnecessary columns. 
2. creating 10 rows for every standard. Again this is wrong coz the roll no will not be primary key.

I think u got the point

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. But the thing is we don't need the aggregate of all the years, but for every year. Like -> The roll no of student, his 1st standard aggregate, 2nd standard aggregate, 3rd standard aggregate .......... so on. So when a student is selected we will be able to see his total academic progress. I told them two answers 1. creating 10 columns for every standard. This was put as wrong because of unnecessary columns. 2. creating 10 rows for every standard. Again this is wrong coz the roll no will not be primary key. I think u got the point

Answer (score 0):

If this is an interview question, it looks like they would like to check your knowledge on Nested Tables. Essentially you would have one column as roll number, and other column which is a nested table as Class and Percentage.